# Rails Unit Test A Class with .blank? method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class, inside the class there is an instance method like the following:

```
def validates
  @signature.blank?
end
```

I am doing unit testing on this class, when I try to run test, I get following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `blank?' for #<String:0x5449061e>
```

However, when I stop using Rails blank?, and change it to the following it works:

```
if (!@signature || @signature.empty?)
```

Does unit testing in Rails allows use of Rails method?

Comment: You can do `puts $LOADED_FEATURES` to see what libraries are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object'
```

on top of your test file